# Why does MIUI ROM have the FM radio on Samsung Galaxy S2 but other custom ROMs do not?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, miui, fm-radio

I have loved the MIUI ROM because it is the only custom ROM that has FM radio enabled on Samsung Galaxy S2. Why does MIUI ROM have FM radio but other custom ROMs like CyanogenMod do not?

Comment: The FM Radio app was created by MIUI ROM developers, and unless it's open source, other ROMs like CM can't simply use the app. I don't have any sources to back this up though.

Comment: Actually, the app is open-source. It seems the MIUI people have donated it to CM, when they decided to no longer work on it. Here's its repository: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_FM. Sadly, it hasn't had any commits in the past 5 years, at least to the official CM repository...